Web vscode does not use all the screen space on iPad
screenshot
I’m trying to use web vscode on a new iPad Pro. I added it to the homescreen to get rid of the browser bars, but now there is a wide black margin that is not being used at all. Is there a setting to fix this?
When used in Safari, there is a white bar in the bottom as well. I’m using iPad OS 17.5

any relation to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124973 ?
